# How to include template from custom plugin in custom Shopware theme?

Tags: php, templates, smarty, shopware

I'm trying to include a template from a custom plugin inside a custom theme in **Shopware 5.2**.

The theme template contains the following line:

```
{include file="frontend/custom/colorpicker.tpl"}
```

The plugin template is located in `/custom/plugins/PLUGINNAME/Resources/views/frontend/custom/colorpicker.tpl`

I get the following error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SmartyException: Unable to load template snippet
>   'frontend/custom/colorpicker.tpl' in
>   'frontend/detail/index.tpl|frontend/plugins/seo/index.tpl' in...

I already tried to add parent to the file path, but with no joy. The error message goes away, but the template is not loaded:

```
{include file="parent:frontend/custom/colorpicker.tpl"}
```

Unfortunately I could not find anything in the Shopware documentation, stating whether there is anything special needed to include templates from a Plugin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding the class variable `protected $injectBeforePlugins = true;` in your themes `Theme.php`

https://developers.shopware.com/designers-guide/smarty/#inheritance-and-plugin-templates

Comment: This seems to be the correct approach, thank you very much! Unfortunately I don't have time to set it up and give it a try now. But once I've confirmed it, I will accept your answer.